# Solving linear equation with large numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

I have equation of form `a+b*n1=c+d*n2`, where a,b,c,d are known numbers with around 1000 digits and I need to solve n1.

I tried:

```
i=1
while True:
    a=(a+b)%d
    if(a==c):
        break
    i+=1
print(i)
```

, but this method is too slow for numbers this big. Is there some better method to use in this kind of situations?

Comment: 1. Try to simplify the equation as n1 = (c - a) / b + (d / b) * n2. 
2. find the greatest common divisor for pairs (c-a), b and d, b 
3. reduce the fractions

Comment: Are you only looking for integer solutions?

Comment: `n2` needs to have a value, too, or the most you can do is define `n1` in terms of `n2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find `x` such that `x = a (mod b)` and `x = c (mod d)`. For then, `n1 = (x - a) / b` and `n2 = (x - c) / d`.

If `b` and `d` are coprime, then the existence of `x` is guaranteed by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) -- and a solution can be found using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

If `b` and `d` aren't coprime (that is, if `gcd(b, d) != 1`), then (noting that `a = c (mod gcd(b, d))`), we can subtract `a % gcd(b, d)` from both sides, and divide through by `gcd(b, d)` to reduce to a problem as above.

### Putting it into code

Here's code that finds `n1` and `n2` using this method:

```
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)

def modinv(a, m):
    return egcd(a, m)[1] % m

def solve(a, b, c, d):
    gcd = egcd(b, d)[0]
    if gcd != 1:
        if a % gcd != c % gcd:
            raise ValueError('no solution')
        a, c = a - a % gcd, c - c % gcd
        a //= gcd
        b //= gcd
        c //= gcd
        d //= gcd
    x = a * d * modinv(d, b) + c * b * modinv(b, d)
    return (x - a) // b, (x - c) // d
```

And here's some test code that runs 1000 random trials of 1000-digit inputs:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

import random

digit = '0123456789'

def rn(k):
    return int(''.join(random.choice(digit) for _ in xrange(k)), 10)

k = 1000

for _ in xrange(1000):
    a, b, c, d, = rn(k), rn(k), rn(k), rn(k)
    print a, b, c, d
    try:
        n1, n2 = solve(a, b, c, d)
    except ValueError, exn:
        print 'no solution'
        print
        continue
    if a + b * n1 != c + d * n2:
        raise AssertionError('failed!')
    print 'found solution:', n1, n2
    print
```

(Note, the recursion limit has to be increased because the `egcd` function which implements the Extended Euclidean algorithm is recursive, and running it on 1000 digit numbers can require a quite deep stack).

Also note, that this checks the result when a solution is returned. But when a != c (mod gcd(b, d)) and the exception is raised signalling no result, no check is done. So you need to think through if this can fail to find results when solutions *do* exist.

This runs (1000 trials) in around 7-8 seconds on my machine, so it performs reasonably well.

Comment: Thank you this worked! One notice though, that you can use the iterative method for gcd, represented here [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), instead of the recursive one, so that there is no need to increase the recursion limit. Feel free to add that to your solution.